# How to write urlpatterns in django?

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I have this structure of urls:
`page/section/subsection/article`, where `section`, `subsection` and `article` are user-generated slug names.

How can I write the `urlpatterns`? 
I do this, but may be exist better method?

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.section),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/(?P<subslug>[-\w]+)/$', views.subsection),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/(?P<subslug>[-\w]+)/(?P<articleslug>[-\w]+)/$', views.article)
]
```

My views:

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'MotherBeeApp/index.html', {})


def section(request, slug):
    sections = Section.objects.filter(page=slug)
    if sections:
        return render(request, 'MotherBeeApp/section.html', {'Sections': sections})
    else:
        return render(request, 'MotherBeeApp/404.html', status=404)


def subsection(request, slug, subslug):
    subsection = Section.objects.get(link_title=subslug)
    articles = Article.objects.filter(section=subsection.pk)
    page_title = subsection.title
    return render(request, 'MotherBeeApp/subsection.html', {'Articles': articles, 'PageTitle': page_title})


def article(request, slug, subslug, articleslug):
    article = Article.objects.get(link_title=articleslug)
    return render(request, 'MotherBeeApp/article.html', {'Article': article})
```

Comment: Which django version do you use?

Comment: django.VERSION 1.11.16

Comment: You can check this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/#example and by the way django 2+ has cleaner url patterns.

Comment: url pattens is about regex pointing to a view. I don't see how this can be improved

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **Django version** older than `Django 2.0` (*< 2.0*) than you are doing right thing and you are already using optimistic way. but if your **Django version** is later than or equals to `Django 2.0` you could write urlpatterns as shown [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/#example).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can upgrade your Django to 2.0+, and then use code as follows:

```
from django.urls import path, include
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index),
    path('<slug:slug>/', include([
        path('', views.section),
        path('<slug:subslug>/', views.subsection),
        path('<slug:subslug>/<articleslug>/', views.article),
    ])),
]
```